# Azure - "Ghost" (Hidden) Network Adapters

Tags: networking, azure, adapter, hidden

I have noticed that every time a VM is shout down and dealocate, as soon as it start up again a new network adapter is created with a # at the end of its name.

Some times our VM had connectivity issues when trying to access shared folders or even connecting to the AD. Did some research online an that was caused because of the ghost network adapters created every time a VM is turned off and on again.

To resolve those issues I had to go to the device manager (since I have only Windows machines), select to show hidden devices and then uninstall all ghost network adapters.

I need azure to stop creating those network adapters or get a tool or script to remove them every time the server is started.

Found this forum complaining about the same thing but no one answered it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/21c1918c-2cc6-497f-9681-0d7c30bb0188/vms-in-virtual-network-w-sts-lose-connectivity?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

Comment: have a +1. Can also add that this "feature" can and will break search on SharePoint dev machines in the cloud